# How to Simulate Typing in an Input Box with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I am trying to do is make the input box think that I am typing numbers into it rather than changing the value of said input.  So the first thing I did was make the input box a variable:

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll("input")[1];
```

Then what I did was focus the input box to make it seem like I had clicked in it with my mouse:

```
input.select();
```

This is the part that I am now stuck on.  What I would like to do is make the input box think that I typed a number into it, say, 41.  If anyone could please tell me what code I need to put into console to make the input box think I typed in "41", it would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `setTimeout` and add one character each time like this :

```js
var input = document.querySelectorAll("input")[1];
input.select(); // you can also use input.focus()
input.value="";

var text = "41";
var l=text.length;
var current = 0;
var time = 1000;


var write_text = function() {
  input.value+=text[current];
  if(current < l-1) {
    current++;
    setTimeout(function(){write_text()},time);
  } else {
    input.setAttribute('value',input.value);
  }
}
setTimeout(function(){write_text()},time);
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

This will work with any content you want to write, you simply need to adjust the variable with what you need.

Comment: that kind of worked, but it didn't do quite what I want it to do.  I forgot to mention that the input box is prefilled with "0".  So when I run that function, it adds 41 to the end of it, making it display "041" in the input box.  Also, when I write "input.select();", would that simulate me clicking behind the "0" in the input box?  Thanks for the help. @Temani Afif

Comment: @MartyMcFarty if you want to ommit the 0, you can add at the start `input.value=""`. And the input.select() will simply add the focus. Check again the answer i updated to get rid if 0

Comment: @MartyMcFarty maybe you want to simulate deleting content and then writing new one ?

Comment: Ty. That got rid of the 0.  But it still isn't quite working how I want it to.  The script I am trying to write is going to write into an input box how many coins I want to place onto a color (Roulette).  So when I type into the input, "41", and click on, say, the red roulette button, it adds 41 coins to red.  But when I use your code, it only changes what number is displayed in the input, rather than changing how many coins would be placed on red.  So I was wondering if maybe instead of making the input box display a number, if it would be possible to simulate me typing "41".

Comment: @MartyMcFarty i think you are using input type number ? as in my code am using input text since i don't have enough information about your script

Comment: the input type is "text"

Comment: is there a way you can show me your complete script ?

Comment: I will explain what I want my script to do to you, then I"ll show you what I've written so far.  So I am writing a script for a roulette gambling website.  The input variable I've made is the input box where you type how many coins you want to place on a color.  What I want the script to do is place a bet on red after the wheel just spun to a green.  The amount I want to place on red is 3, and then if that loses, i want to increase the bet to 3x3, and then if that loses I want to set the bet to 9x3, etc.  So for now what I am trying to do is make the amount of coins I will place 3

Comment: var redButton = document.querySelector('div.enter-btn.red.enabled')


var lastColor = document.querySelector('.roulette .status .timer .header');


var baseBet = 3



//Count greens and reds as wins, blacks as losses

var placeBet = document.querySelectorAll("input")[1];

Comment: @MartyMcFarty i meant a complete HTML/CSS/JS code :) . Of course my code will not do what you expect as i don't have the information about the remaining page ... So if you can use https://jsfiddle.net and make a complete code i can help you ;)

Comment: the HTML/CSS/JS code doesn't work when I put it into jsfiddle. :(  It just gets stuck on the loading screen of the website when I put it into there.  I have no idea how to fix it, because it's not my website.  Thank you for the help, though

Comment: @MartyMcFarty maybe you have a link to the website ?

Comment: it's a csgo gambling website, so you would need a steam account in order to login.  Do you have a steam account?  If so, I do have a link.  If not, that's ok.  I still really appreciate you helping me

Comment: @MartyMcFarty i think i find a work around for you issue ... i think at the end of the simulation we should update the value attribute, so i have updated my code, you may try it again if still interested :)

Comment: thank you, but that still isn't fixing it.  It does change what is displayed in the input box, but the amount of coins that would be placed does not change.  Do you think if I used EventDispatcher and dispatched a keyboard input of 3 that it would possibly fix it?

Comment: @MartyMcFarty not sure .. maybe since you have the value stored in a variable you can directly use it where you want (the else i made is when the simulation is done, so ther you can update the value of the coins)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't fix it for me.  Sorry, I think the only way to solve it would be for you to see the website.  But since you need a steam account, you can't.  Thank you for trying to help me though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160487/discussion-between-temani-afif-and-martymcfarty).

Answer (score 14):

I know this was really really long ago, but I'm currently working on a very similar problem and encountering the exact same issues that the original poster was encountering, and I found this code snippet ([credit](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/simulate+keyboard+input+javascript)):

```
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
    key: "e",
    keyCode: 69,        // example values.
    code: "KeyE",       // put everything you need in this object.
    which: 69,
    shiftKey: false,    // you don't need to include values
    ctrlKey: false,     // if you aren't going to use them.
    metaKey: false      // these are here for example's sake.
}));
```

And the specific key codes you need can be found [here](https://keycode.info/).

This is definitely an extremely overcomplicated way of doing things, you'd need something to translate whatever input string you have into a list of instances of KeyboardEvent, and then dispatch them one by one, but as far as I can tell this is the proper way to truly "simulate" keyboard input.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to come up with a Chrome extension which acts as password filler for twitter but simply setting the input value does not work. Can you help me with it?

Comment: @John you might try writing it to user's clipboard?